# Не могу понять почему не работает Array List: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java

Выдает ошибку

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList (java.util.Arrays$ArrayList and java.util.ArrayList are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at List1.list(Okruzhnost.java:29)
    at Okruzhnost.main(Okruzhnost.java:22)
```

не понимаю, как это исправить. подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

```
public class Okruzhnost{
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int x1 = 5,y1 = 6,x2 =7, y2=10; 
       int dx=5; int dy=5;
      
      Okruzhnost1 tom = new Okruzhnost1(); 
      
      tom.print1();
      tom.line();
      tom.dx();
      tom.line();
      tom.move(dx, dy);
       tom.print();
          
       List1 List = new List1();
       List.list();
  }
}
class List1{
  void list() {
  ArrayList<String> list;

  list = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b" ,"c"});
  System.out.println("Размер массива равен"  + 
  Integer.valueOf(list.size())+ "элементами");
  }
}
......
class Okruzhnost1{
...}
```

Answer (score 6):

[Причина в том, что:](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/855-10-oshibok-zachastuju-dopuskaemihkh-java-razrabotchikami)

> `Arrays.asList()` вернет объект класса `ArrayList` который является
> внутренним приватным статическим классом (`private static class`) класса
> Arrays, а это не класс `java.util.ArrayList`. Класс
> `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` содержит методы `set()`, `get()`, `contains()`,
> но не содержит никаких методов для добавления элементов, его размер
> фиксирован.

Можно не конвертировать тип и работать через `List`:

```
class List1{
    void list() {
      List<String> list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b" ,"c"});
      System.out.println("Размер массива равен " + list.size() + " элементами");
    }
}
```

Но если нужен `ArrayList<String>`:

```
class List1{
    void list() {
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b" ,"c"}));
      System.out.println("Размер массива равен " + list.size() + " элементами");
    }
}
```

---

**PS.**

В `Arrays.asList` можно вместо массива передавать параметрами:

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b" ,"c")
```

Comment: спасибо, я пыталась добавить или удалить элементы в этой части кода                         
     list = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a", "b", "c"});
но они не удаляются и не прибавляются. это какой-то особенный список ?

Comment: кажется я все поняла))) очень интересно. спасибо)

Comment: а как вы узнали. что это приватный статистический класс ?

Comment: @DailyChinese, по названию класса в ошибке видно, что тот класс является подклассом (`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`) ну и в документации можно подглядеть, например в https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...) . И, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: спасибо.я. имела ввиду по какому именно слову или знаку или последовательности. вы поняли, что это подкласс?